# how to Set attributes JsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm trying to execute

```
jQuery("#surveyManager").jstree("create", jQuery("#" + parentId), "last",  
                { "title" : "new_node", 
                  "attr" : { id:"Clone" } },
                    false, true);
```

But this is not setting the attribute for the node in the jstree. Please advice how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this replacing the inner element you passed with null as the jstree is instantiated on #surveyManager

```
 jQuery("#surveyManager").jstree("create", null, "last",  
                {"attr" : { id:"Clone" },{"title" : "new_node"} },
                    false, true);
```